# matplotlib gives ImportError: No module named six

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using python 2.7 with matplotlib 1.4.3. When I try to run a simple program I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Projects\ImgRecg\img.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Six module.

```
pip install six
```